# KMDF lower Filter driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kmdf

I am writing an filter driver and want to attach the filter to more than one physical keyboard in the system.
If I attach the filter to the first keyboard "\Device\KeyboardClass0" it works fine but it works not for the other.
The IoAttachDevice failed for "\Device\KeyboardClass1". The same with other class. I have attached 3 physical keyboard.

**status = IoAttachDevice(gkbdDevice, &TargetDevice, &((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)gkbdDevice->DeviceExtension)->kbdDevice);**

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is it possible to attach the keyboard filter to all keyboards at once?

Comment: you even not say which `status` return to you `IoAttachDevice`. in many case `IoAttachDevice` can fail due `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag on device, when it already open. need use `IoCreateFile` with `IO_ATTACH_DEVICE` options + `IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe`. and doubt that you use really kmdf driver

Comment: Before I call IoAttachDevice I call "status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&devName, FILE_ALL_ACCESS, &pFileObject, &(pLBKdev));" This function also fails with return "0".

Comment: The IoGetDeviObjectPointer returns with STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION on the second or third keyboard. Why this?

Comment: exactly because i wrote - use `IoCreateFile` with `IO_ATTACH_DEVICE` options

Comment: and you never must use hard-coded `\Device\KeyboardClassX` names for open device. need open lower device by interface name - `IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification` with `EventCategoryDeviceInterfaceChange` on `GUID_CLASS_KEYBOARD` . and got device name on `GUID_DEVICE_INTERFACE_ARRIVAL`

Comment: thanks. It is not clear for me.I take IoCreateFile like this but how do I use the result in IoAttachDevice  HANDLE hFile;
 OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, Notification->SymbolicLinkName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
 IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
 
 status = IoCreateFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN, 0, 0, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, 0, IO_ATTACH_DEVICE);

Comment: you need use `IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe`, returned file handle you need convert to file object (`ObReferenceObjectByHandle`) and then to device - `IoGetRelatedDevice` . and use interface name, instead `\Device\KeyboardClassX`

Comment: I get now:
 RtlInitUnicodeString(&devName, L"HID\\VID_046A&PID_010D&MI_00\\7&48EAABC&0&0000");

 HANDLE hFile;
 OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &devName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
 IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
 status = IoCreateFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN, 0, 0, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, 0, IO_ATTACH_DEVICE);

 CreateAndAttachDevice, IoCreateFile failed to call:0xc000003b

Comment: from where you got `"HID\\VID_046A&PID_010D&MI_00\\7&48EAABC&0&0000"` ? are you hardcoded it ? of course must be error `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_SYNTAX_BAD` - correct - you need got interface link from `IoRegisterPlugPlayNotification` callback

Comment: Yes I see but at the moment I don't want write IoRegisterPlugPlayNot... If we decide to write a driver we implement it with kdmf 2. I've seen in the examples that this is a better way. For now I want to add it hard coded. You said interface name. What name is it for the keyboard?

Comment: something like "\\??\\HID\\VID_046A&PID_010D&MI_00\\7&48EAABC&0&0000" must be - you forget root folder \??\

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I can now open a second keyboard but ...

```
    /*
* Form the Device Name and symbolic name
*/
RtlInitUnicodeString(&devNameFlt, L"\\Device\\KeyboardClass0");
RtlInitUnicodeString(&devName, L"\\Device\\MultikeyboardCnt");

status = IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION),
    &devName,
    FILE_DEVICE_KEYBOARD,
    SYNCHRONIZE,
    FALSE,
    &pDevObj);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("%s, IoCreateDevice failed:0x%0x\n", __FUNCTION__, status);
    return status;
}

HANDLE hFile;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, 0, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };
oa.ObjectName = &devNameFlt;

IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
status = IoCreateFile(&hFile, SYNCHRONIZE, &oa, &iosb, 0, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN,
    0, 0, 0, CreateFileTypeNone, 0, IO_ATTACH_DEVICE);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("%s, IoCreateFile failed to call:0x%0x\n", __FUNCTION__, status);
    return status;
}

/* Get File Object */
PFILE_OBJECT LocalFileObject;
status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(hFile,
                                   0,
                                   *IoFileObjectType,
                                   KernelMode,
                                   (PVOID*)&LocalFileObject,
                                   NULL);

pLBKdev = IoGetRelatedDeviceObject(LocalFileObject);
DbgPrint("%s at IoCreateFile ok\n", __FUNCTION__);
ObReferenceObject(pLBKdev);

/*
* Retrieve device extension pointer from device object
*/
pDevExt = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION)pLBKdev->DeviceExtension;

status = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe(pDevObj, pLBKdev, &pDevExt->kbdDevice);
if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceObjectPointer failed with error = 0x%0x\n", status);
    goto cleanup_failure;
}

pDevObj->Flags |= DO_BUFFERED_IO;
pDevObj->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

/*
* Create the symbolic link name, this is not mandatory
* but can be helpful for user mode apps to communicate
*/
status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&symLinkNameFlt, &devNameFlt);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    // if it fails now, must delete Device object
    DbgPrint("IoCreateSymbolicLink failed with error = 0x%0x\n", status);
    goto cleanup_failure;
}
```

but the routine DispatchRead crashes if I type a key on the keyboard.

Comment: The problem is that in the DispatchRead function in the call to IoCallDriver(pDevExt->kbdDevice, Irp); the pointer pDevExt->kbdDevice is NULL. Why this because it worked before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe() after DO_BUFFERED_IO and ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING.

```
pDevObj->Flags |= DO_BUFFERED_IO;
pDevObj->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

status = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe(pDevObj, pLBKdev, &pDevExt->kbdDevice);
if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    DbgPrint("IoGetDeviceObjectPointer failed with error = 0x%0x\n", status);
    goto cleanup_failure;
}
```